# Is there a way to pass many arguments and not have an ugly url?

Tags: 7, uri, views

I'm writing a module that displays graphs based on a selection of arguments (an array with items to display, a daterange and some other stuff). This results in a long and ugly url.

Is there a way to get the arguments to the page with the graphs without putting everything in the url for that page? I'm looking for something that can keep temporary variables with a short reference that I can pass in the url, but haven't been able to find anything.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be a simple one: put the urls with an index in the session, pass the index as an argument to the next page and once there lookup the url again in the session.

Comment: Of course, this solution means that you can't use the same URL to always arrive at the same graph. That's the tradeoff.

Comment: Agree with rfay, this precludes the ability for a user to send the graph page to a friend via hyperlink, for example.

Comment: True, but in this case that is not a problem. But well pointed out, thanks.

Comment: you could use ctools object cache if you don't want to fool around with creating your own index: http://uppitywis.org/help/ctools/object-cache

Answer (score 1):

You could use form submission or cookies to store values, but neither of these are a particularity good ideas.

I would recommend (if you don't like the URL showing) using AJAX to retrieve/update the graph. You still have the ugly url but you hide it inside the ajax request.

So your module displays

/mypath

but the request could be

/mymodule/displaygraph/x/as/32432/s///

Comment: I am already using AJAX to get the actual graph data from a (Drupal) webservice. But I need some way to get the parameters selected by the user across to the page that displays the graph. Would you suggest to submit those via ajax and do a page reload?

Comment: In this case, why not just use ajax to bring back the graph, rather than a page with it embedded.

Comment: I could do that, but the layout of that page does not allow for the graph.